# Switching between activities with java animation (defined programmatically)

Tags: android, android-animation

If i have my animations defined in xml then i can animate between activities like

```
//Calls a new Activity  
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  

//Set the transition -> method available from Android 2.0 and beyond  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,R.anim.push_up_out);
```

But I have my animation defined in Java. Function "overridePendingTransition(int , int)" takes int arguments for animations. How can I use programmatically defined animations instead?

Comment: Why have you downrated thi question. If you can add a comment for down rating that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out solution for this here
http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/comment-page-1/#comment-12025